# DI, WPF, Разрешение зависимостей

Tags: c#, архитектура, inversion-of-control, di

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть следующая архитектура

```
IRepository(DBContext context)
IService (IRepository repository)
```

Дальше WPF

```
IModel(IService service);
IViewModel(IModel model);
```

В `App.cs`, в методе `OnStartup`, конфигурируется приложение с помощью IoC контейнера.

`MainView` содержит много окон. Если передавать `MainView(IViewModel childParent)`, то все зависимости разрешаются сразу на момент создания `MainView` но что, если таких `childParent` много и сразу все конфигурировать не нужно, а например, только по нажатию кнопок в `MainView`.

Какие есть подходы?

---

MainWindow - обычная форма для открытия дочерних окон

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
   DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

внутри MainWindowViewModel должны открывать дочерние окна со своими IViewModel.

например new View(IViewModel viewModel).Show() IoC контейнер сконфигурирован в OnStartup Application Как передать в MainWindowViewModel IViewModel.

Если через конструктор, то 1) таких интерфейсов будет много 2) даже если окна не нужны их, ViewModels будут сконфигурированы. Это избыточно

Comment: Как то непонятно, поясните вопрос начиная с MainView. Приведите много детелей, как вы релизуете MainView  и дочерние страницы

Comment: MainWindow - обычная форма для открытия дочерних окон
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
   DataContext = viewModel;
}

внутри MainWindowViewModel должны открывать дочерние окна со своими IViewModel.
например 

new View(IViewModel viewModel).Show()

IoC контейнер сконфигурирован в OnStartup Application

Как передать в MainWindowViewModel IViewModel. Если через конструктор, то 
1) таких интерфейсов будет много
2) даже если окна не нужны их, ViewModels будут сконфигурированы. Это избыточно

Comment: Мне кажется, что вы сильно усложняете свою архитектуру, оно вам точно нужно ? Я понимаю использование репозиториев(хотя многие считают их избыточночтью, особенно если юзать ОРМ) и сервисов и их инжекцию через DI. Потом, у вас есть сервисы, а что у вас за модели ? они содержат какую то логику или это просто данные(анемичнная модель) ?  И конечно ViewModel, вот тут я совсем не уверне имеет ли смысл их инжектить через DI ? они у вас реально как то переиспользуются, вот лично у меня это очень редко )) нужно понять в чем смысл DI - это возможность быстрой подмены реализаций(один из смыслов)

Comment: У вас строка содержит new (вот эта: `viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel()`) и это убивает всю идею с DI на корню. Фактически вы сделали DI и им не пользуетесь, а потом спрашиваете вопрос "а почему у меня DI так плохо выглядит?". Правильно: на конструктор MainWindow должен приходить IViewModel viewModel, в конструкторе присваивается this._viewModel  = viewModel а вот что именно MainWindowViewModel должен использоваться в качестве реализации IViewModel  -- это должен сделать/разрезолвить ваш IoC-контейнер. Понимаете, new в коде -- это зло, если вы решили использовать DI/IoC.

Comment: Это я понимаю. но я спрашиваю о дочерних viewModel, которые должны конструироваться по требованию при обработке command в MainWindowViewModel.

Comment: Ну и конструируйте, проблема-то в чём? Вы пишете одно, а спрашиваете про другое. Например, знаете что странно? Вы говорите "и тьма-тьмущая у меня интерфейсов", окей принято. Но в вопросе пишете ОДИН пример одного интерфейса. И где тьма-тьмущая, чтобы это стало проблемой? Пока видно один красивый чистый интерфейс. Попробуйте привести показать свои десятки интрейфесов, которые якобы мусорят вам код, подумайте в чём их однотипность -- тогда наверное мы поймём вашу проблему. Пока не видно.

Comment: У меня по работе есть проект в котором мне тоже не нравился конструктор с семью зависимостями, но я же не прибегал ни к кому с вопросом "а почему DI такой плохой?". В какой-то момент пересобрал иначе в голове предметную область и разбил на другие классы, где по 2-3 зависимости было. Красиво! Но DI как до этого был, так и после остался. И эту проблему я мог красиво завуалировать использовав Mediatr, который стал бы единственной зависимостью, которая бы резолвила бы остальные, но я оставил как есть, чтобы эта проблема была видна и не уходила из поля внимания.

Comment: Что DI, что IoC ни жарко ни холодно ваше число зависимостей в классах, это не они рождают эту проблему и не им её решать. Поэтому ваш вопрос не о DI -- ваш вопрос о архитектуре "что-то я наплодил много интерфейсов, не нравится" (с напрашивающимся ответом "так, а не плодите")

Comment: По конкретным интерфейсам. Во-первых, я не особо шибко много сталкивался с WPF, поэтому просто как вопрос: у меня вызывает сомнение, что вам нужно чтобы модель зависела от сервиса (`IModel(IService service)`) или в иных терминах, чтобы представление зависело от бизнес-логики: обычно достаточно чтобы dto'шку возвращаемую сервисом представление могло отрисовать. Второй момент - по классическому разделению на сервисы и репозитории: у вас DbContext - это уже набор репозиториев, поэтому в реальном приложении сервисы можно завязывать на DbContenxt , а не лепить "репозторий поверх репозитория".